# ValueError while finding best hyperparameter in Scikit learn LogisticRegression using GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, hyperparameters, nlp

While doing hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV for LogisticRegression, I am getting error as
`ValueError: Invalid parameter Hparam`

For estimator:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=-1, penalty='l1', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=1, warm_start=False)
```

I've written my code below:

```
hparam=[]
a = 0.0001
while(a<100000):
    hparam.append(a)
    a*=2
LReg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1',verbose=1,n_jobs=-1)
param_grid = {'Hparam':hparam}
grid_ = GridSearchCV(LReg, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', cv=10)
grid_.fit(xtr_,ytr_)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer sci-kit Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), Hparam is not listed as a hyper parameter for Logistic Regression